# Laravel 11 + Livewire mount method not working anymore

Tags: livewire-3, laravel-11

Livewire 3 seems not working right with laravel 11

I just start a fresh Laravel 11 installation + Livewire 3
A simple test component seems not work like usually

Component

```
namespace App\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public $test;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->test="Hello!";
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}
```

View

```
<div>
   {{ $test }}
</div>
```

Seems mount method not working anymore, i changed with __costrunct() method, and $test is now correcly istantiated, but is not available in view so, for make this code run i have to do this change:

Component

```
namespace App\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{  
    public $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test="Hello!";
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test', ['test' => $this->test]);
    }
}
```

This is normal, or i miss something?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

A new fresh installation (with same dependies as previous) work correctly.
I actually dont know what caused the problem described.